# How to pass a proxy object to another class?

Tags: java, proxy, webdriver

I have a setup with webdriver and BrowserMob Proxy to run some selenium tests and get the har file while doing it.
I have a CustomDriver class, where I put my setup for my driver.
The proxy is defined here as well.

I want to pass the proxy element to another class.

I've tried to pass the proxy object but everytime it gives a nullpointer exception.

Custom driver class:

```
public WebDriver newDriver() {
proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(enable);

proxy.start(0);

switch (config) {
 case "chrome":

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","PATH TO MY DRIVER")
    seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,seleniumProxy);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

break;

public static BrowserMobProxy getProxy() {
  return proxy;}
```

The other class I want to use the proxy:

```
 BrowserMobProxy p = MyCustomDriver.getProxy();
p.newHar();
```

But I still get a nullpointer every time.
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Please reformat your post so that it isn't a pain to read (especially the code parts). Also include how and where you want to pass the proxy instance to your custom driver and ideally provide the implementation of `MyCustomDriver.getProxy()` - that call looks like `getProxy()` is a static method.

Comment: I reformatted my post

Comment: Assuming you get the NPE at `p.newHar();` I'd assume that you didn't initialize `proxy`. Did you call `newDriver()` at any point before calling `getProxy()`?